# Check certain check boxes after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

Hi Guys I need to have certain check boxes checked after a make an ajax request.

the ajax request does pull the check boxes from another page and the jquery used is on the orginal page. Im not sure how to go about this i am trying :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(function()
    {
        $("#selectall").on('click', function(){
            $('.case').attr('checked',this.checked);
        });

        $(".case").on('click', function(){
            if($(".case").length==$(".case:checked").length)
            {
                $("#selectall").attr("checked","checked");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
    });});
```

Which works fine when there is no ajax request involved. I would like to knwo if anyone could help me find a way to allow the checkboxes to be checked when using ajax requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery "on" http://api.jquery.com/on/ in order to bind the click even after ajax load...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/>

<SCRIPT>
$(function(){
    $("#selectall").on('click', function(){
        $('.case').attr('checked',this.checked);
    });

    $(".case").on('click', function(){
        if($(".case").length==$(".case:checked").length)
        {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked","checked");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: thanks, im getting an error now saying object has no method on would i need to put this function in the document.ready in jquery ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using jQuery v1.7 and above?

Comment: Yep, that's coz the .live was replaced with .on from jQuery v1.7 onwards. Recommend you to move from .live to .on as .live has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better to check the checkboxes in the page that is fetching these checkboxes.
So load the html with ajax, than on load complete check the boxes

Answer (score 0):

**You need to delegate the events..**

As the checkboxes are not yet available on the page when the events are bound. So delegating them to a static parent container should solve the issue.

```
$(staticContainer).on.('click', "#selectall", function ({
    $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(staticContainer).on.('click', 'case', function () {
    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length {
        $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

And it is always a good idea to uncheck your check boxes instead of removing it's attribute.